# How to disable trigger from managed package?

Tags: trigger

Im trying to insert some Opportunities, but i get this error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
         error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved because 
    it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with
         version ID xxxxxxxx. Contact your administrator for help.: []
```

Im working on sandbox and this trigger comes from managed package, so i cant just deactivate it.

Comment: Is that flow your or from managed package? quick answer is no unless creators of managed package allow to do it.

Comment: The trigger comes from managed package :)

Comment: But I have asked about flow/process builder. is that from managed package?

Comment: I have checked debug logs and it failed with the trigger from package. No flow mentioned. You think that i can query by the version id of flow? And if so, how? I think it would solve this question, becouse i can see some flows binded to opportunity.

Comment: Idea would be next - open workbench, login to your org, on Jump To select Metadata Types and components, click select, from dropdown click Flows, click expand all, and search by flow id. Then, go to flows and disable corresponding flow. If you dont see that in flows, go to processbuilder, find it and disable. Then do your deployment, enable that back. Grab a beer and improve your tests to avoid failing on flow or make flow more restricted to fire in less cases =)

Comment: SOQL would be more smooth, but thanks anyway bro :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1.Uninstall the application that's causing this .To do this it's important to note business impact of removing the package .Keep this as last option.

2.Go back to the publisher or owner of the application and ask them to fix this issue. The publisher can debug or figure root cause via their LMA or ISVForce .

Prefer this over first but if option 1 has no impact just ask users to stop logging and you can do data load and restore back the package once you are done with load .

Comment: im afraid, that both options are too much time consuming :/